# DTCoreText Linker Error, undefined symbols

Tags: objective-c, linker, ios6

I've used DTCoreText in the past, but I'm trying to use it via the Static Library in the latest version. I've followed all the setup points outlined on the GitHub README (even in a fresh blank Xcode project). However when trying to define NSAttributedString render options like in the demo. I just get linker errors

`NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Times New Roman", DTDefaultFontFamily, @"purple", DTDefaultLinkColor, nil];`

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_DTDefaultFontFamily",
>   referenced from:
>         -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o   "_DTDefaultLinkColor", referenced from:
>         -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o

Not sure what I'm missing, but I've looked over it several times. Anything I should be looking out for?

Comment: Where did you find the static? Did you make it on your own? Seems it's not compiled it for i386 architecture. type "lipo -info libCoreText" for further details

Comment: It's a target dependency, which I assume tries to compile it before compiling my project? The DTCoreText project is a sub-project of mine. Where do I type "lipo -info libCoreText" in Xcode?

Comment: Ah think I got it now. Had to also link to the binary and link to the MobileCoreServices framework. Thanks

Comment: Why is MobileCoreServices framework required?